# Is there a way to quickly find a particular comment I made?

Tags: support, comments

I know I can go through my comments using the "all actions" tab on my user profile but after a little over a year that list is 1250+ entries and growing. So I was wondering if there is a way to search my comments by keyword somewhere that I haven't found, or a search term that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no on-site way to search comments that I know of, but for comments old enough to be in SEDE (updated every Sunday), you can use [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/893715/search-a-users-comments) to find comments from a particular user containing a particular string.  It's just a SQL "like" operation, not a boolean search, so don't try to get fancy. :-)

The query takes a user number as a parameter.  You can get that from the URL of your profile page; in your case it's 40408 (on this site).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this, works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

**Another way** is to use your favorite google engine and prepend your search terms with "stackexchange:" (For example, I just entered **stackexchange: elemtilas tree kite** and got all the responses and got all the Q&As where my name plus the words "tree" & "kite" show up anywhere in the same query.

- **PROs**: this method "looks" nicer than the SEDE search. It actually presents links to SE questions. Also, you don't have to hunt around for your member id number! :)
- **CONs**: the key word you're looking for could be *anywhere* on the page, not necessarily in your comment! So some detective work might be in order.

If you use this method, try to enter as many keywords as you can remember from the comment you're thinking of!